# Redirect to custom tab in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, tab, redirect

I have custom tab in lightning experience that include lightning component.
How can I redirect to this tab using client controller?

URL of this tab:

> https://kasyan-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#eyJjb21wb25lbnREZWYiOiJvbmU6YXVyYUNvbnRhaW5lciIsImF0dHJpYnV0ZXMiOnsidmFsdWVzIjp7InRhZyI6ImM6QXBwcm92YWxzUGFnZSJ9fSwidCI6MTQ4MTIwMDQyNTQzNn0%3D

I can to hard code this url but I am not sure that this token won`t changed...

Comment: Your question seems unclear ... plz could u detail ?

Comment: is your tab a lightning tab or visual force tab? is it component or app?

Comment: from what i can tell so far - locker service would not allow you to modify the url of the current window. you better use the event model for navigation.